# Matching a nonquoted string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to work with regexes in PHP on my school's news site (running WordPress). The idea is, whenever someone saves a post, all instances of "Regis" (without 'Jesuit' at the end) are replaced with "Regis Jesuit." (I go to Regis Jesuit High School, and they're picky about their branding). Overall this works fine with the following case-insensitive regex:

```
/regis(?! jesuit)/i
```

How would I modify this regex so it doesn't match if it finds the string "Regis" or 'Regis' (in single or double quotes)? (or even "I go to Regis High School" quoted as well)? The idea here is to change it where necessary, but to keep it the same in direct quotes in people's stories so we don't change people's quotes.

Thanks!
Morgan

Comment: The problem you are going to run into is matching pairs of quotes. In the sentence `"I went to Regis High School," said recent Regis grad John Integer, "but I don't have my Regis alum card yet."` it is going to be very difficult to tell any regex parser that the middle case is not between two quotes. Also, since AP style calls for quotes to start a paragraph quotation *but not to end it if the subsequent paragraph is a continuation of the quote*, it gets very tricky indeed.

Comment: Also, assuming that all people know or care for correct quoting, or that they use *only* single or double quotes and never forget to close quotes is a *little* too optimistic. *Besides: You don't want to change "quoted" text. Stuff people enter in a text field **is** quoted text, no matter if they quote somebody else in their post. Think about that.*

Comment: Oh, and before I forget: Assuming that "Regis" never means anything else than your school is short-sighted to say the least. Do a Google search for "Regis" and be amazed by how many different things it can mean.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Maybe I should rethink a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, perhaps a solution would be to stick with your current regex, but use it as a client-side JavaScript warning only.

So, if the text entered matches "regis" not followed by " jesuit" then before the user submits simply displays a message saying "make sure you've correctly branded us", but which doesn't automatically change anything - basically leaving the language complexity stuff to the brain of a human who can (hopefully) understand it. :)

Comment: I see where you're going with this. However, I think I discovered a better solution.

Managing newsteams of high school guys is hard enough. We've tried the solution you suggested before and it hasn't worked too well. People call the school "Regis" but the school wants it branded as "Regis Jesuit." Still, no one listens.

Comment: 95% of the time our writers refer to Regis Jesuit as "Regis" too.
The solution (in my opinion) is to use the same regex I had earlier, with one modification:

/(?<!\\[\\[)regis(?! jesuit)(?!\\]\\])/i

I've set it up so that people can enter "Regis" by itself ONLY if they enter it as "[[Regis]]" (the other 5% of the time). A filter changes it back to "Regis" when the post is displayed.

I think this is the best solution because it doesn't eliminate the choice of just saying "Regis".